# How should BDD statements be properly constructed? Is there a convention used in teams?

Tags: bdd, ui-automation, gherkin

Is there a preferred way of creating BDD scenarios in small agile teams and amongst the community? I'm using courgette and it gives an example on https://courgette-testing.com/bdd

```
Scenario: Refunded items should be returned to stock
  Given a customer previously bought a black sweater from me
  And I have three black sweaters in stock.
  When they return the black sweater for a refund
  Then I should have four black sweaters in stock.
```

Does this sound like a good idea? Would this work well for communication in teams?

I've used their web steps bit, and am now doing the refactor bit to make it clear to the business.

Any links would help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversations in BDD are more important than the tools. Rather than starting with the finely-grained specification in Courgette's example, try talking to the business first. Ask them for an example of the kind of behaviour they want.

When you write it down, start by just writing it the way they describe it. It's amazing how few people listen properly! After you've got the example from them, take a look at it. Can you see which bits are the contexts (Givens) and which are the outcomes (Thens)? Which is the step that's associated with triggering the behaviour you're interested in (Whens)?

Once you've worked that out, there are a couple more questions I like to ask:

- Is there any other context which, for this same event, gives a different outcome?
- Is there any other outcome that's important?

For instance, if I was implementing this behaviour for a big supermarket, I might come across an example like:

> "Oh! No, don't add food back to stock. We don't know how it's been stored. We refund it if there's something wrong with it, but we bin it."

You can probably see how that might change your code!

Testers are really great at asking these questions and spotting missing scenarios! This leads us to the "Three Amigos" pattern. I like to include:

- A business person, Product Owner, subject matter expert or person with the problem
- A tester
- A dev (or a pair of devs).

You can also include UI designers, technical writers, etc. - Matt Wynne says it's "Three Amigos where three is a number between 3 and 7".

I really like it when the developer writes the scenarios down, in any form that allows them to get to the "Given, When, Then". Sometimes I'll do it in the meeting; sometimes I do it later and show it or send it to my business person.

Courgette's example is something that typically happens when people don't have these conversations. If you start with the conversations, you're much more likely to get something that matches the above. Not only are those declarative steps easier for business to read and for the whole team to talk about, but they're also easier to maintain, as the detail of how they're achieved is hidden (usually in Step Definitions, and further in Page Objects).

There's all kinds of useful posts for BDD newcomers [on my blog](https://lizkeogh.com/category/bdd/) if you want to know more!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. From using Courgette it feels like there is a direct relationship between the declarative scenarios and the granular web steps do you not think? And it seems we could still do it how you're describing with Courgette, just the other way round. We would like to automate some happy paths running against different browsers so the tools are also important to us. It'll be really nice to have the green light running tests on scenarios that have been built through collaboration. Thanks again!

Comment: The automation will be exactly the same but with a layer of abstraction over it. That layer will be based on a new, happy understanding of not just *how* the software needs to behave, but *why*. So yes, automation is still a thing! For the scenarios already in place, if not too many then refactor exactly as you're doing; have conversations pragmatically for stuff you've already done. This may help: https://lizkeogh.com/2014/01/22/using-bdd-with-legacy-systems/

Comment: Great to hear you're using Courgette @ManojPatel

Hi Liz. I created Courgette because of seeing Cucumber being used to create web steps, rather than declarative scenarios. It seems like if devs get their hands on Cucumber tools, then that's their immediate goto, to create custom granular web steps because without an abstraction, going from declarative scenarios to automated tests takes a lot of effort and can create an absolute mess or both. I spoke with Matt Wynne and he wants to see this part of Courgette's functionality in every flavour of Cucumber. Can you also see the value in it?

Comment: I highly value your opinion too @Lunivore

Maybe it'd be better to word the BDD page the other way round so it's clear it should ideally be conversations first.

My last job was at a law firm, and two of the lawyers (product owners) were actually away writing tests after an hour intro into the dom, CSS and XPATH selectors, and a bit of context on html. One was super involved and started to maintain the test suite. Was quite interesting to see. It was a realisation I'd certainly reduced the barrier to entry.

Comment: @alexrogers The page as it is is a great guide for refactoring from the POV of people who started with the tools; it's a very common anti-pattern. I reckon just call it out as that and put a bit about conversations at the beginning. More importantly, if Courgette is different to other BDD tools out there, please do call out the difference really explicitly! Diverse approaches are great IMO; I see the value. From a StackOverflow perspective your copy of your comment which you posted as an answer needs some fleshing out; address it to OP instead of me and it will probably be good.

Comment: That was a complete accident and I thought I already deleted it :S Will do! Great!! Means a lot. Noted, will get onto that!